# How to parse a complex XML using Xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath, saxparser

I have an XML as below :

```
<Service xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="someurl" xsi:schemaLocation="someurl Sample.xsd">
    <RequestControl>
        <requestID>100129</requestID>
        <Control>
            <requesterName>Admin</requesterName>
            <requesterLanguage>100</requesterLanguage>
        </Control>
    </RequestControl>
    <Inquiry>
        <InquiryType>getParty</InquiryType>
        <InquiryParam>
            <Param name="PartyId">854850029276139020</Param>
        </InquiryParam>
    </Inquiry>
</Service>
```

I want to extract the value "getParty" from  tag using XPath XML Parser. I am using the below as my expression :

```
expression = xPath.compile("/Service/Inquiry/InquiryType/text()");
```

How can I write the accurate and complete java code for the above? I just want to extract the value for `<InquiryType>getParty</InquiryType>`.

Comment: I am using below : 
NodeList xpathNodeList = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
         System.out.println("xpathNodeList length is : " +xpathNodeList.getLength());

However it print length as 0.

Comment: Try using `XPathConstants.STRING`

Comment: It says :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String incompatible with org.w3c.dom.NodeList

Comment: @Som, using your code I get xpathNodeList.getLength() = 1

Comment: @jeanr : Could you please help me out more on this.. in my case it shows 0 as length. I have double checked again.

Comment: I add the code I used below. You can share me yours if you want me to check

Comment: @jeanr : I have pasted my code after your code. Please check once where I am doing wrong.  Is it something to do with 


Document doc = builder.parse(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/test.xml");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the below method :

```
public static String inputXmlXPathParser(String inputXml){


        //==================================================X-Path Parser =============================================================//

        String transactionName = StringUtils.EMPTY;

        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource( new StringReader(inputXml)));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

            XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
            XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("/Service/Inquiry/InquiryType/text()");
            NodeList xpathNodeList = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            System.out.println("InquiryType is : " +xpathNodeList.item(0));

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    


        return transactionName;

    }
```

Comment: @jeanr : I could print the root element correctly, however not the   "xpathNodeList.item(0))" . It prints null.

Comment: my code working fine after I have removed namespace stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Trying your code, it looks like it is working fine for me. Here is what I did

```
public static void main(String ... args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException, XPathExpressionException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/test.xml");
    XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("/Service/Inquiry/InquiryType/text()");
    NodeList xpathNodeList = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    System.out.println("InquiryType is : " +xpathNodeList.item(0));
}
```

With test.xml containing exactly the xml you are using

```
<Service xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="someurl" xsi:schemaLocation="someurl Sample.xsd">
<RequestControl>
    <requestID>100129</requestID>
    <Control>
        <requesterName>Admin</requesterName>
        <requesterLanguage>100</requesterLanguage>
    </Control>
</RequestControl>
<Inquiry>
    <InquiryType>getParty</InquiryType>
    <InquiryParam>
        <Param name="PartyId">854850029276139020</Param>
    </InquiryParam>
</Inquiry>
</Service>
```

Comment: @DanielHaley, by default the document builder is not namespace aware so you might get away with the used path if there is only a default namespace and no prefix used in the XML. Other implementations like Saxon however want a namespace aware DOM I think.

Comment: I got where I was doing wrong. I was using the below line :

dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

When I commented out the code it just works fine.